# How to make declaration of Typescript RecursiveOmit and RecursivePick for cloning methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have been trying to make a declaration for the RecursiveOmit and RecursivePick for cloning methods JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, ['myProperty']))

```
type RecursiveKey<T> = T extends object ? keyof T | RecursiveKey<T[keyof T]> : never; 

type RecursivePick<T, K> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? (T[P] extends object ?  RecursivePick<T[P], K> : T[P]) : never
}

type RecursiveOmit<T, K> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? never : (T[P] extends object ? RecursiveOmit<T[P], K> : T[P])
}

const clone = <T, K extends RecursiveKey<T>>(object: T, whiteListedProperties: K[]): RecursivePick<T, K> => { 
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object, whiteListedProperties as (string | number)[])); 
}

const cloneWithBlackList = <T, K extends RecursiveKey<T>>(object: T, blackListedProperties: K[]): RecursiveOmit<T, K> => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object, (key: string, value: any): any => blackListedProperties.includes(key as K) ? undefined : value));
};


const c = {
    a: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    },
    b: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
}

const cc = clone(c, ['b']);


cc.b.a = 2 // error a shouldn't exists on cc.b 
cc.b.b = 2; // b should exists on cc.b
cc.a.c = 2 // error c shouldn't exists on cc.a 

const cb = cloneWithBlackList(c, ['b']);

cb.a.a = 2; // a should exists on cb.a  
cb.b.b = 3; // error b shouldn't exists on cb 
cb.a.c = 2; // c should exists on cb.a
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIGkIgB4AVAPigF4oioIAPYCAOwBNUoB7AIwCsFgoA-FADW+dgDMqUAD6wEKDNjyEiAbVEgJVALpkAXFEYRsyANxQAsAChroSHKRosEAArp4w4gBooOMpQBvaygQqFUXKHRGETFJIm0DCLoGFjYcQSgACjUXbRp6JlYOHj4MhwVnNw9icO0fPygDHO0ASkbDYwhkawBfa1twaDhHRQgAeQBbdGBvX38oIKtQsIiomM04hKgkgtTfDKMTduza-JSirl54fiFhiuxJ6Zrc+v0qWpbe-qt4dkZUfjwAA2f2glFm6WShTYdycSnwxBIJEylz4TR8AHcABbTCAAGXQAIgzBcyHYkGQwHQEFQBhwqlaBlhoyqniIrwoZACliWoWQEGAKGiACkAMpjAByADowABDNAQTJiyVSgHIKIAc3Q4hAKJK10xOIYBKJJLJFKpNKgsrYmTVmpkhkQE04XRaDJaLXMXxsPz+AKgwNBAHVpliAEJA2UeE38cHs-ZQvbM5zKRHI1HXdFQThRmOEhhm8ldS203wepnyOHjKYzBMNchc4JQfmC5Ai8XSuUKpWd1XAdWMLU6vVXYA+TIaAz2oc+TCyoGICAGWWMEAtFdrzk5vPCWPE0nFynU1BSqLAxDMGmT-DWtJtISIFgQcRRYnteeLiCe0y9X++6xfn+QEKAWZsQllAxFmWZZIKgABGLxwJgzgDAAJiQ3kYMDAwAGZkJ6TDllQsCsJguDEOQ4j0IIn1AP9QF4FAoMjEyeAfFUAByThONaf9vngeApU4KVZVAtCoAAekkmhkDJZBrSgVAsXYRAgWYRhOP4OgCzYP5AyEzgeUE4ThPE8xpJzJSVLU5h8l0jhohMzhAKE2UpSYygJMsrp5MDazVPUzTtNoBz9JMsSBIYwMjMoFiIFDYAI13WM2I47jeK9ASRPcsSvIsmSxOUwK7J0gE9KcnKQkAkTatA3CCtkvyjOK2zgvs8rHJi4yco88ypJkpjWvUjrgAqmLRKgIA)

I have been trying all kinds of variations of this and different/similar answers from other questions. But I was not able to get it working.

Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "*I was not able to get it working*" - what is not working?

Comment: What's the point of `extends RecursiveKey<T>`?

Comment: Looks like a bug... workaround: https://tsplay.dev/mL3gaN

Comment: @vr. your solution looks promising, just that Omit should work in reverse compared to Pick, but that I can correct.
Thank you
If you want you can make a normal answer and I can make it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This seems like a bug in TypeScript to me.</strike> I have not found any issues on GitHub pertaining to this issue, but nevertheless, the workaround I have found is as follows. First, clean up the type definitions with [key-remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), and [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)/[`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers):

```
type RecursivePick<T, K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in Extract<keyof T, K>]: T[P] extends object
        ? RecursivePick<T[P], K>
        : T[P];
};

type RecursiveOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P] extends object
        ? RecursiveOmit<T[P], K>
        : T[P];
};
```

Then we can change the functions, using 5.0 `const` generics:

```
const clone = <T, const K extends RecursiveKey<T>>(
    object: T,
    whiteListedProperties: K[]
): RecursivePick<T, K> => {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object, whiteListedProperties as any));
};

const cloneWithBlackList = <T, const K extends RecursiveKey<T>>(
    object: T,
    blackListedProperties: K[]
): RecursiveOmit<T, K> => {
    return JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(object, (key: any, value: any): any =>
            blackListedProperties.includes(key) ? undefined : value
        )
    );
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIGkIgB4AVAPigF4oioIAPYCAOwBNUoB7AIwCsFgAoKEKgB+KAGt87AGZUoAH1gIUGbHkJEA2pJAyqAXRKDhALiiMI2ZAG5+-UJCVI0WCAAV08ccQA0UHDT0TKxQbsjskMig6mSUAN7GQppuUOiMUACi9MgAhvDABDp6RH44JPpmWm76gQwsbFy8+YnCQmJwzqrunt5V+qVGra2Vyfq2AL629uDQHSquAPIAtugFJf61wWxhERBRIDEUUAmtyanpWfAANojMEIVSsutlFVSjm-UcPHwtre3KLmwy1WxFGA1+pje1QmU3g7EYqGAUGu8OglF8yPhiI2dDqITmgNw+GIJBIAAoWo0+JUfC0AO4AC1WEAAMuhERBmDtIsB0BBUGYcJp9PwAJRmAldDxeDFlChkE7CZAQYAodIAKQAygsAHIAOjAOTQEDJWt1esRyDSAHN0NIQGSqfk-IzmWyOVzwjy+Wwcr7GCBRaKYXY4QikSiLAB1VYMgBCVzy4ndSPR6zD2ICuK2TnmamJpHJlO++RpLU4ia8Kc53L2vP5guFYolAK6wLWA3lxxaytVyA12v1huNFKGwjN+stNrtDqdwD8ZJ0ZhyAb8mByNwgy4D4qgK5A8ohY4rSernt2UR9erS11u-MX+FFoigiBYEGkaU5UDM683R6gootMG-CTKGWIRkcipCDkZhQUMMFQAAjLSY5CJwZgAEwoah8BmAAzNhQjjIRUDod2qF7mYyH-mRWEtMRIGwuByLwEckYmvAfiaAARJw3H6MB-DwPAeqcHqORHBh1hQAA9DJNDIOEyB7lAqAMuwiBXMwjAAORInQ7LAA06TCaJQkiWJnCSdJcmkap6macwgSGcZLFmaZOR6qxlBSbJ8l7EpyL2RpWm6fptAuRwJkiTkYHhsiVmUOxMbAPGlbJoZZKcVAPF8QJsJiZ5Ek+TZ8kSWpIVOQZiKufAhVCZZolHHhpUKYFVkVY5YXOTVUUJQ14ledZflBZ1Wk9UZfV1eJ-BAA)

Comment: Wow nice, this seems to work correctly of TS 5.0, I forgot to mention in the initial question that I am using TS 4.9.5, will see if angular15 will work with TS 5.0 and  I can update it.

Comment: Yeah, angular15 doesn't work with TS 5.0 have to wait for release of angular16 to be able to use `const K`.

Comment: @Darkwander You could still use my original playground in the comments that doesn't use `const` generics.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from hovering over the function call, the "problem" is that `K` is inferred to be `"a" | "b" | "c"` (i.e. `RecursiveKey<typeof c>`) and not just `"b"`.

You can fix that by being explicit (`clone<typeof c, "b">(c, ["b"])` or `clone(c, ['b' as const])`), but also [TypeScript 5.0 has just the solution for this problem: `const` type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters):

```
const clone = <T, const K>(object: T, whiteListedProperties: K[]): RecursivePick<T, K> => {…}

const cloneWithBlackList = <T, const K>(object: T, blackListedProperties: K[]): RecursiveOmit<T, K> => {…}
```

<sup>([updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.0.2&ssl=13&ssc=100&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIAV3wGsAeAFQBooBpAPigF4oBvAWACgoOoBtHKdAOygEIIAPYAzKCQC6ALii8IAD2AR+AE1RUoAfigAKEj2lRlqjVtEAjAFYJgujnCRosufMSM5pFGlHle0gCU-lD8ENjIbAC+bGygkLAIKBjYAPIAtujApL60DCzsnDx8gsJikjLyiipqmtp64ZGhhsamtRZQ1nbwDnrOKW6Z2aTGeaGBQTFxrPCi-KgO8AA289AMuVBzCw40+t32ARQA7gAW2RAAMuiLEOo4yKKQyMDoEKjylFzB8gOu2HhCJs-HRaIwoGxOFBkBBgChBAApADKaQAcgA6MAAQzQEH0yLR6MWyAEAHN0OIQPtbPYTudVNdbvdHs9Xu8oFitPpiWSoAAfMKIDJWCDIILfIJBADcENYsVYbG2iy2q3CAHVsqcAELLLGERkODbkLbzZV7A69I5QKy6-U3VTMp6itkfKgS37Jf4QYY5Y0gsGQ6Gw+FQAkY7G4-EojE8-jkynUnrACj6cryWOkiiYLHLRAQeRY-ggIIFov0Wg2vUEA13B5Ol5vVDogQrRDqd6pkQcrSUEJ6RAaCDiAR3ULZ3MQSVSmLThVzpVLehMQMcLHyQpQqFrqAARjIK83VnkACZ90VN1t5ABmA-RM9Qo-L8+b7d7g8Pk+36bz01LeBLlY1n0eAKC4AByKwwOCWcZngeB0SsdEsSXY8oAAejQ0xkEeZAOSgVBTlERBlnUfgwIcZR7UsQQ4IQ2VaMQqwUJlDDrXwwjiPUdoqK6Gj4KsRV4KxdF-wYVDWNFHCtnYoiSLIiilB4+YtiE2VFV-LYmIYQD1U1HUqwNYDQIgqDpVgxDhOQsSWMw5CCNkrjKMWajNKQjhFUYuiGCvGysKkpj7M4+TuOc3jNPoiyROY9DMP-QKSJC4AXPgCyoCAA))</sup>

Comment: Hmm, neat, but why is it inferred incorrectly in the first place? It does not seem to be a regression from 4.9 to 5.0.

Comment: This doesn't error if an invalid key is passed.

Comment: It's not inferred incorrectly. `["b"]` is value of the type `("a" | "b" | "c")[]`.

Comment: It should be inferred as `"b"`, not `"b" | "a" | "c"`.

Comment: Sure, that's what the `const` tells it to. Not saying that `"b" | "a" | "c"` isn't undesirable here, just that it's not a bug in TypeScript.

Comment: "*This doesn't error if an invalid key is passed*" - you can add `extends RecursiveKey<T>` after the `const K`, but I don't see a reason to consider keys that do not appear in the input as invalid.

Comment: Right, good point. I think in [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4jr7N), for `fn4`, `K` should still be inferred as `"a"`, but now I do see why it is not.

Comment: @Bergi I would like to consider invalid keys in the input that don't exits on the input object, since it helps if you make a typo or input a non existed key.